# How to get Bundle product minimum price for each group programatically

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I'm developing an api in Magento 2 that will return bundle products minimum prices for each group. Magento shows the price on front end when particular customer of a group logged in, in my case customer will not logged in. I am using below code for each available customer group by passing group id but it gives same price in all customer group.

```
$product->setCustomerGroupId($groupId);
$bundleObj = $product->getPriceModel()->getTotalPrices($product, null, null, true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you found any solution? Im facing same issue for M1.9. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278457/m1-9-to-get-calculated-customer-group-prices-for-bundle-products-using-product